# Electric field of battery

Tags: electric-fields, batteries

What happen when a charge particle is kept between the two electrodes of battery ?

Will the electric field between those two electrode affect that charged particle?

Answer (score 0):

> Will the electric field between those two electrode affect that charged particle?

Yes.

The positively charged electrode causes positively charged ions to drift away toward the negatively charged electrode which attracts them. However, diffusion causes positively charged ions to tend to redistribute in a manner that equalizes their concentration throughout the electrolyte. Analogous processes occur with the negatively charged ions.

Negatively charged ions losing their negatively charged electron to an electrode is oxidation, and positively charged ions becoming neutral by gaining an electron at an electrode is called reduction. These reactions occur whenever current is flowing externally between the electrodes, either in charging the battery or (in reverse during) discharging. This causes a sharp gradient of ion concentrations near the electrodes. However, drift due to the electric field, and diffusion due to thermal motion still play their role, even though the concentration of the ions and the electric fields change rapidly near the electrodes.